# How to have nested element width exceed parent element

Tags: html, css

On my navigation bar I have a dropdown menu, I want the dropdown portion to exceed the width of the dropdown link. Currently it seems that it is being limited by it and I cannot figure out to how to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="site-nav">
   <div class="menu-primary-menu-links-container">
      <ul id="menu-primary-menu-links" class="menu">
         <li id="menu-item-36" class="standard-nav-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/contact/">Contact</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-37" class="standard-nav-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/tuition/">Tuition</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-38" class="standard-nav-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-38"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/blog/">Blog</a></li>
         <li id="menu-item-107" class="standard-nav-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-107">
            <a href="http://localhost/testsite/shop/">Gallery</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
               <li id="menu-item-119" class="dropdown-nav-link menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-119"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/product-category/animals/" class="nav-link-a">Animals</a></li>
               <li id="menu-item-120" class="dropdown-nav-link menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-120"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/product-category/contemporary-space-images/" class="nav-link-a">Contemporary Space Images</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li id="menu-item-42" class="standard-nav-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-42"><a href="http://localhost/testsite/">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Navigation Menus */
.site-nav ul {
    font-family: LibreCaslonDisplay;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.site-nav ul:after {clear: both;}
.site-nav ul { *zoom: 1; }

.standard-nav-link {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.nav-link-a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 85px;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.nav-link-a:hover {
    background-color: #b0a59b;
    color: white;
}

#header-logo {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 220px;
}

header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited {
    background-color: #b0a59b;
    color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Dropdown Menu */

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #b0a59b;
}
.sub-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.sub-menu a:hover {
    color: #ebebeb;
}
.sub-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 400px;
}

.standard-nav-link:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    width: 85px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that because the menu div is nested inside the navbar, that means that the menu div is bound by the size of its encompassing navbar.
The easiest way around this to move the menu div outside of the navbar div.

You can add styles to correctly position the navbar and div.